# Export invoices from Magento to QuickBooks

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, extensions, export

Looking to export invoices from magento and import them into QuickBooks. It doesn't matter which version of QB but please reference Magento 1.9 solutions, if possible.

- Has anyone built a module for this?
- Are there extensions available?

Comment: Visit Magento Commerce and search for QuickBooks. There are few paid ones available. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be useful

Here is **/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepository">
        <plugin name="Company_quickbooks_plugin_sale_order_invoice"
                type="Company\QuickBooks\Plugin\Sale\Order\InvoiceRepository"
                sortOrder="2"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And **Company\QuickBooks\Plugin\Sale\Order\InvoiceRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\QuickBooks\Plugin\Sale\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Company\QuickBooks\Helper\Data;


class InvoiceRepository
{

    /**
     * @var Data
     */

    protected $data;

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;


    public function __construct(
        Data                     $data,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository

    )
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function afterSave($subject, $result)
    {
        
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($result->getOrderId());
            $idCustomer = $this->data->getIdCustomerQuick($order->getCustomerEmail(),$result->getOrderId());
       
            foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $idItem = $this->data->getIdItem($item->getSku());
                $TaxCodeRef=$this->data->getTaxCodeRef($item->getSku());
           
                $items[] = array("DetailType" => "SalesItemLineDetail", "SalesItemLineDetail" => array("TaxCodeRef" => array("value" => $TaxCodeRef), "ItemRef" => array("value" => $idItem), "Qty" => $item->getQtyInvoiced(), "UnitPrice" => $item->getPrice()), "Amount" => $item->getRowTotal());
            }
            $params = [
                "DocNumber" => $result->getIncrementId(),
                "CustomerRef" => [
                    "value" => $idCustomer
                ],
                "Line" => $items,
                "CurrencyRef" => [
                    "value" => $result->getOrderCurrencyCode(),
                ],
                "ShipMethodRef" => [
                    "name" => $order->getShippingDescription(),
                    "value" => $order->getShippingDescription()
                ]
            ];
            $this->data->postInvoice($params);
       
    }
}
```

**Company\QuickBooks\Helper\data.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\QuickBooks\Helper;

use Company\MagApi\Model\Requester;
use Company\QuickBooks\Model\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper as BaseAbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class Data extends BaseAbstractHelper
{

    protected $Curl;
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @var Requester
     */
    protected $requester;

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $orderRepository;


    /**
     * AbstractHelper constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Config $config
     * @param Curl $Curl
     * @param Requester $requester
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Config $config,
        Curl $Curl,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        Requester $requester
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->requester = $requester;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->Curl = $Curl;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

   

    /**
     * @param array $params
     * @return Response
     */
    
    public function postInvoice(array $params)
    {
        $token = $this->config->getToken();
        $url = $this->config->getUrl();
        $response = $this->requester
            ->setToken($token)
            ->post( $url, $params);
        return $response;
    }
}
```